# set select option from json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have function to call `json` value
Now when user opens account edit page I would need the country to be selected by default when the page opens

```
var url_country="<?=base_url()?>country.json";
 var negara_list ="<option value=''></option>";
    $.getJSON(url_country, function(data) {
      $.each(data,function(key,val){
         negara_list += "<option value="+val+">"+val+"</option>";
      });
      $(".negara").html(negara_list);
  });
```

Comment: you need `selected` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, hope this will help you

```
var url_country="<?=base_url()?>country.json";
var user_define_country = 'USA';
var negara_list ="<option value=''></option>";
    $.getJSON(url_country, function(data) {
      $.each(data,function(key,val){
         if(user_define_country == val){
            negara_list += "<option value="+val+" selected='selected'>"+val+"</option>";
         }else{
            negara_list += "<option value="+val+">"+val+"</option>";
         }
      });
      $(".negara").html(negara_list);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, if your json response is only one country then, No need to play `each` function, if your response more than one country then you would specify which country is going selected as default

For response with single country

```
    var url_country="<?=base_url()?>country.json";
    var negara_list ="<option value=''></option>";

    negara_list += "<option value="+url_country.country+" selected>"+url_country.country+"</option>";

       $(".negara").html(negara_list);
    });
```

For response with mutiple countries

```
    var my_country = "United States"; // country which is going to auto selected

    var url_country="<?=base_url()?>country.json";

    var negara_list ="<option value=''></option>";

     $.getJSON(url_country, function(data) {

       $.each(data,function(key,val){

          if(my_country == val)
          {
              negara_list += "<option value="+val+" selected>"+val+"</option>";
          }
          else
          {
               negara_list += "<option value="+val+">"+val+"</option>"; 
           }

         });

       $(".negara").html(negara_list);
    });
```